# In selenium, when I search Xpath how do I capture the element two positions before?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, tags, selenium-chromedriver

In Python 3 and selenium I have this script to automate the search of terms in a site with public information

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Driver Path
CHROME = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
CHROMEDRIVER = '/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver'
# Chosen browser options
chrome_options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME

# Website accessed
link = 'https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica?PaginaAtual=2&Passo=7'

# Search term
nome = "MARCONI FERREIRA PERILLO JUNIOR"

# Waiting time
wait = 60 

# Open browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER, options = chrome_options)
# Implicit wait
browser.implicitly_wait(wait)
# Access the link
browser.get(link)

# Search by term
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='NomeParte']").send_keys(nome)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnBuscarProcPublico']").click()

# Searches for the text of the last icon - the last page button
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divTabela']/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a").text
element
'»'
```

This site when searching for terms paginates results and always shows as the last pagination button the "»" button.

The next to last button in the case will be "›"

So I need to capture the button text always twice before the last one. Here is this case the number "8", to automate page change - I will know how many clicks on next page will be needed

Please, when I search Xpath how do I capture the element two positions before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not an answer to the original question.
But clicking the next button several times is not a good practice.
I checked the network traffic and see that they are calling their API url with offset parameter. You should be able to use this URL with proper offset as you need.
[image]

If you really need to access the last but two, you need to get the all navigation buttons first and then access by indexing as follows.

```
    elems = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    elems[-2]
```

## EDIT

I just tested their API and it works with proper cookie value given.
This way is much faster than automation using Selenium.
Use Selenium just to extract cookie value to be used in the header of the web request.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @David Piao. Can I edit my question above and put the solution attempt with your approach? I am having difficulty using the request. Should I use POST?

Comment: The black screen image you showed is not the Inspect element, right? Is it a software?

Comment: The black screen is from Postman - a very good tool for API testing