# With python and requests, how to make a correct POST call and where to find the headers?

Tags: python, networking, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I accessed the site below that has public information and tracked the results in the Inspect Element

At the [link](https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica?PaginaAtual=2&Passo=7) I typed the name "MARCONI FERREIRA PERILLO JUNIOR" in the "Nome da Parte" field and then clicked the "Consultar" button

Below is a list of lawsuits

In Inspect element, in the "Network" tab I saw that there is a "Request URL:"  https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica (with POST method)

I followed my friend's suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863479/in-selenium-when-i-search-xpath-how-do-i-capture-the-element-two-positions-befo) and tried to create a Python script on requests to capture the search result in JSON format. I tried like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica"

header = {
    'Cookie': 'style=null; WIDPJP=.cp06-2:cp06-2; JSESSIONID=h_9l1zwHbaWGL2pPbVTyf8alvfVUREhUbCtqNGxN.cp06:server-cp06-2',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=header)
r
<Response [200]>
```

But what is returned is just the query screen text

Please does anyone know how I can get the correct header information and make the correct call?

I'm trying to find the solution pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863479/in-selenium-when-i-search-xpath-how-do-i-capture-the-element-two-positions-befo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Network tab and right-click on the network request, and choose "copy -> copy as cURL", you get something like this:

```
curl 'https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Origin: https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Referer: https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica?PaginaAtual=2&Passo=7' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Cookie: WIDPJP=.cp03-1:cp03-1; style=null; JSESSIONID=kMiu0qC-d11BAdWVd6QoJM837YUXuTsWVgTofjLk.cp03:server-cp03-1' --data 'chamadaAjax=true&tabela=1&offset=0&PassoEditar=12&consultaPronta=true&' --compressed
```

You can then use a tool like https://curl.trillworks.com/ as an easy way to convert this from cURL format to requests format, and end up with

```
cookies = {
    'WIDPJP': '.cp03-1:cp03-1',
    'style': 'null',
    'JSESSIONID': 'kMiu0qC-d11BAdWVd6QoJM837YUXuTsWVgTofjLk.cp03:server-cp03-1',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Origin': 'https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica?PaginaAtual=2&Passo=7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

data = {
  'chamadaAjax': 'true',
  'tabela': '1',
  'offset': '0',
  'PassoEditar': '12',
  'consultaPronta': 'true',
  '': ''
}

response = requests.post('https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

# Edit: If you want to get all the pages of data, you can do something like this: 

response = requests.post('https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

TOTAL = response.json()['total']

offset = 0

values = []

while offset < TOTAL:
    data['offset'] = str(offset)
    response = requests.post('https://pjd.tjgo.jus.br/BuscaProcessoPublica', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
    rows = response.json()['rows']
    offset += len(rows)
    values += rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Zachary Blackwood. But please, the response.text result is not the JSON list of the search result. That is, the columns and rows: "Número Processo Polo Ativo Polo Passivo Data da Distribuição - 5196250.77 MARCONI FERREIRA PERILLO JUNIOR JUNIO ALVES ARAÚJO (MAJOR ARAÚJO) 15/08/2016 - 5274034.33 MARCONI FERREIRA PERILLO JUNIOR QUID NOVI CONSULTORIA LTDA - ME 20/10/2016..."

Comment: Sorry, now I think I get it. I always have to capture the second "BuscaProcessoPublica" - xhr

Comment: unfortunately, does this have to be done for each of the 8 separate pages? Is there a whole list way that appears on all pages?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves I've added some code at the bottom to loop through all pages until you've fetched all the rows

Comment: Thank you very much again @Zachary Blackwood.  But this way I got the headers manually - one query at a time. Would this kind of site be able to automate the search and then the collection of each header? If you want I can put an example search I did in selenium